# append svg:text below each rect element

Tags: d3.js

Are having a hard time to figure out this problem.

i.e. if has a svg

```
<svg>
<rect id='1'></rect>
<rect id='2'></rect>
<rect id='3'></rect>
<rect id='4'></rect>
</svg>
```

how can I append a svg:text below each rect using selectAll and enter function?
(actually using json data set)

I want to result such below...

```
<svg>
<rect id='1'></rect>
**<text>text here...</text>**
<rect id='2'></rect>
**<text>text here...</text>**
<rect id='3'></rect>
**<text>text here...</text>**
<rect id='4'></rect>
**<text>text here...</text>**
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Javascript data to generate these elements, the pattern would look something like this.

```
var data = [1,2,3,4];
var sel = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter();
sel.append("rect").attr("id", function(d) { return d; });
sel.append("text").text("...");
```